# How the compiler displays *inaccurate* value of float?

Tags: c, math, floating-point

**I would like to know the mechanism why the compiler shows inaccurate value of float**. Example

```
float a = 0.056;
printf("value = %f",a); // this prints "value = 0.056"
```

If you try to store 0.056 in binary floating point format, you get this ([use this link for conversion](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html))

> 0.00001110010101100000010000011000 which is equal to 0.0559999998658895

**1. How the compiler shows 0.056 while it should show 0.055999999?**

Lets take this example a little further

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
float a, b;

a = 0.056;
b = 0.064; // difference is 0.08 

printf("a=%f, b=%f",a,b);

if( b - a == 0.08) // this fails
    printf("\n %f - %f == %f subtraction is correct",b,a,b-a); 
else
    printf("\n%f - %f != %f Subtraction has round-off error\n",b,a,b-a);
}
```

Note that else block gets execute here while we expect if block to be correct. Here is the output.

```
a=0.056000, b=0.064000
0.064000 - 0.056000 != 0.008000 Subtraction has round-off error
```

Again the values are shown the way we expect (with no round off error) but these values do have round off errors but false disguised values are shown.  My second question is

**2. Is there a way to show the actual value of the stored number rather than the disguised one that we entered?**

*Note: I have include C code in Visual Studio 2008 but it should be reproducible in any language.*

Comment: [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=what+every+computer+scientist+should+know+about+floating+point) "what every computer scientist should know about floating point"

Comment: I mean I know it, I want to know how the compiler displays the binary value inaccurate which fools the programmer too?

Comment: it's not about the compiler, it's about the implementation of `printf`

Comment: @pmg - there are plenty of those kinds of questions on SO, but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: @Joe - notice I provided that as a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Sure! I have made that comment myself before.

Comment: Mmh... You seem to be getting `0xCAC083` as your mantissa, but I get `0xCAC084`, which makes up for the difference between 0.0559999998658895 and .05600000172853469848

Answer (score 11):

The compiler doesn't show anything 😉 Your program shows 0.056 because `%f` only show the result up to 6 digits. Try `%.16f` if you want to see all the inaccuracies (Result: http://ideone.com/orrkk).

The [manpage of printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) shows many other options you can use with these specifiers.

Comment: and `printf` is rounding the values, not truncating.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: Sorry I was missing a `.`. `%16f` sets the width to 16, `%.16f` sets the precision to 16. See update.

Comment: Now this `a=0.0560000017285347, b=0.0640000030398369` again since this is float not a double thats why you see discrepency after 7 digit. In essense it is still .056 and .064

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: Not sure what you mean. You cannot store 0.056 or 0.064 exactly whether it's `float` or `double`.

Comment: @KennyTM that is what I am after. If I can't store it accurate, why printf show it accurate. .16 in this case is totally wrong because float has accuracy of upto 8 digits. So I used .8f and I still get 0.056. Now do this `a = 0.056-0.00000001;` .8f now displays a=0.05599999 and you see it does not rounds it. I think the way it works, the compiler internally works on more than 32 bits. If the extra bits value rounds the number to the next bigger number, it round it otherwise it leaves it as it is. But this is my explanation at this point with no proof.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: The "exact" value of that 0.056 is 0b111001010110000001000010 × 2⁻²⁸ (0.056000001728534698486328125), so rounding after 8 digits still gives you 0.05600000. That 0.00000001 is exactly 0b101010111100110001110111 × 2⁻⁵⁰  (9.99999993922529029077850282192230224609375e-8), the subtraction causes this to lose 22 bits of significance to be rounded to 0b11 × 2⁻²⁸ (1.11758708953857421875e-8), so the subtracted value will become (0b111001010110000001000010 - 0b11 = 0b111001010110000000111111) × 2⁻²⁸ (0.0559999905526638031005859375), so after rounding we get 0.05599999.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: The FPU/CPU (not the compiler) does not need to work on more than 32 bits. Remember floating points are computed in *base-2*. You can reason with decimal arithmetic. Please do read "what every computer scientist should know about floating point" as \@pmg has suggested.

Answer (score 4):

In most languages, the routines for printing float values actually print the shortest decimal number that is closer to the float value to be printed than to any other float value. This often (but not always) masks the rounding errors resulting from translation of decimal literals to float values.

Comment: I like your answer but need some depth.

Comment: @The crocodile hunter: depth in what regard?

Comment: how printf works to remove this round off error. It is pretty much mathematical question.

Comment: @The crocodile hunter: It's a very, very complicated task. Here's the source code for OpenJDK: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html (the relevant part is the dtoa() method). That's so much code that there's a stackoverflow question just about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173056/why-does-dtoa-c-contain-so-much-code

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of talking about `printf` and how it is printing stuff "the wrong way" because it rounds things up, etc. `printf` is printing *exactly what you expect*, when you notice that the actual number stored in `a` *is* `0.05600000172853469848`.

OP is assuming that the number stored in there is `0.0559999...`, but a look to the actual number shows that's wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        float a = 0.056;
        printf("%A\n", a);
}
```

That will print `0X1.CAC084P-5`, meaning our mantissa (`0xCAC084`) is `110010101100000010000100`. That's 24 bits, though, not the 23 we can store in a 32 bits (IEEE-754 single precision) floating point, meaning that what's in there is actually `11001010110000001000010`

Remember that the mantissa is normalized and assumed to start by `1` so, applying the exponent, etc, our number is:

```
0.0000111001010110000001000010
```

which translates to `0.05600000172853469848`

OP assumed this, instead:

```
0.00001110010101100000010000011
```

which, certainly is more accurate, BUT that requires a bit more than what the mantissa can store, so we'd end up with this:

```
0.0000111001010110000001000001
```

or `0.05599999800324440002`.

Of course, none of numbers are `0.056`, but the error in the representation is higher for the latter one! So no surprise that we're getting what we're getting...

Answer (score 1):

2) If you have a C99 library, try printing the double in hexadecimal

```
printf("%A\n", 56.0/100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the mistake of assuming that your float was *ever* accurate.

They are not designed to represent a precise value such as `0.0559999998658895`.  Libraries such as [GMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) exist for that.

Floats are designed to be fast and approximate.

In your example, `0.056` is displayed because the digits `0.0559999` are presumed to be accurate and the digits that follow `99865889...` are considered mostly noise and only significant enough to round up `0.0559999` to `0.056`.

`printf` doesn't know that you consider `0.056` to be "correct".  It just knows that a float printed in human-readable format is only accurate to about 6 significant digits, and `0.0560000` represents the closest match using that many digits.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: Edited my response to answer that.

Comment: ok do this. `a = 0.056-0.000000001;' why does it now shows a=0.0559999980032444, why not round it to 0.056 ?

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: When I did what you asked me to do, the result I got was 0.056.

Comment: I put in one extra 0 in there. Plz try 0.056-0.00000001; I think I got it. float internally works on more than 32 bits. If the extra bit rounds the value it rounds it, otherwise it leave it as it is.

Comment: "_a float printed in human-readable format is only accurate to about 6 significant digits_" what?

Comment: @curiousguy: C allows a float's value to be printed in the code in a people-friendly format such as "0.056", even if that value can't be represented by a float.  An approximation will be used in these circumstances.  With the common 32-bit IEEE 754 format, 6 digits of accuracy can be expected from this approximation.

Comment: @DrewDormann IOW, the value will be converted to a decimal representation, truncated to 6 digit?

Comment: @curiousguy: There are additional rules that don't relate to this question. But you are correct that by default, printf won't show more than 6 significant digits of a `float`.  And the reasoning is that additional digits would be mostly noise.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: You are correct, although I don't think the C standard dictates that.  Intel-compatible CPUs have always used 80 bits to represent floating point numbers internally, while IEEE-standard floats promise that each result is rounded to the nearest value, which implies that at least 1 extra bit is maintained.