# How to use DBL_MANT_DIG to check strtod

Tags: c, floating-point

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>

int main (void) {
    double val;
    /* base b = 2; 2^DBL_MANT_DIG */
    /* decimal digits log10(2^DBL_MANT_DIG) */
    /*const char *str = "9007199254740992";*/
    const char *str = "9007199254740993";

    errno = 0;
    val = strtod(str, NULL);

    printf("%d\n", DBL_MANT_DIG );

    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        printf("error\n");
    } else {
        printf("%f\n", val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This returns:

```
53
9007199254740992.000000
```

Since str has a string number that has more significant digits than the my machine can handle, how does one use `DBL_MANT_DIG` or the `log10(2^DBL_MANT_DIG)` version of it to check that the result of `val` is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use those to check that the conversion is exact.

[Here's one way of how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455604/968261).

Another way is to [find out how many decimal digits after the decimal point are there in the resultant `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197157/968261), do `sprintf()` using that as the precision and compare its output with the original string.

Comment: thanks for you suggestions, it's somewhat more complicated than what I hoped for but I'll surely check them out. I'll see if other people perhaps have further suggestions.

Comment: It's not a trivial problem. [A must read](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know that paper and am reading it. I thought since this must be such a common problem that perhaps there is a library or some such.

Comment: When using floating point, fewer people care about precise results than care about consistent results. [Consistency: how to defeat the purpose of IEEE floating point](http://www.yosefk.com/blog/consistency-how-to-defeat-the-purpose-of-ieee-floating-point.html).