# Why does C printf not round up when decimal is 16.125 but will with 16.135

Tags: c

I am using C printf to print doubles and found the rounding is inconsistent. Sometimes it will not round up with certain values.

```c
double t = 16.125;
printf("%-10.2lf", t);
```

This prints 16.12. I thought it would round up to 16.13.

```c
double t = 16.135;
printf("%-10.2lf", t);
```

This prints 16.14. This is what I thought would happen for all cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does printf in C round floating-point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546110/how-does-printf-in-c-round-floating-point-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default rounding behaviour is round-half-to-even.

This means:

- 16.125 is exactly halfway between 16.12 and 16.13, so it rounds (down) to 16.12 (the even one).
- 16.135 can't be exactly represented by a floating-point number. On my system, it's 16.135000000000001563194018672220408916473388671875. This number is closer to 16.14 than to 16.12, so it rounds to 16.14.
- 16.375 is exactly halfway between 16.37 and 16.38, so it rounds (up) to 16.38 (the even one).

[`fesetround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround) allows one to change the default.

Comment: Oh that is interesting. The round half to even matches what I am seeing. Why did you use the closest value to 16.14?

Comment: Re "*Why did you use the closest value to 16.14?*", I don't understand the question. I didn't use the closest double to 16.14. That's `16.1400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`. `printf` produces the string `16.14`.

Comment: I meant 16.135, sorry. that closest value to 16.135 will round to 16.14 because 4 is even and 16.135 would also round. I was just wondering why you choose to use the closest value to 16.135.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh it does not? I did not realize the numbers cannot be represented exactly.

Comment: Re "*I was just wondering why you choose to use the closest value to 16.135*", You mean why did the computer choose that? Why wouldn't it? You think it would choose something further away?

Comment: @Sei4or try it yourself `printf("%.50f\n", 16.135);`

Comment: So when I type 16.135 the language is actually representing that with the closest value it can? I do not understand the round half to even algorithm enough to know why it does not qualify.

Comment: @user3386109, Re "*16.135 doesn't qualify for the round-half-to-even*", oh yeah. duh. Fixing

Comment: Re "*I do not understand the round half*", If the portion to round is exactly 5, it'll pick the even neighbour

Comment: Oh but because of the way the computer represents this number it is not exactly 5 but with 0.375 the computer can represent it exactly and use that rule.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is a much more complicated system than I expected. The edits to the original answer help clarify a lot @ikegami

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you. I assume the computer cannot represent those numbers exactly because of the way the information is laid out in IEEE 754?

Comment: The way I like to explain it: 135/1000 is periodic in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal. Therefore, it can't be stored exactly using a floating-point number. 125/1000 (0.001) and 375/1000 (0.011) aren't periodic in binary.

Comment: @ikegami Oh that makes a lot of sense. I did not realize that.